# Uri of images keeps changing, is this an emulator issue or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: android, uri, gallery

I have set up some code to pick an image from the gallery.

```
private void setImg() {
        Intent imgIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        imgIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(imgIntent, IMG_INPUT);
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == IMG_INPUT) {
                Uri imgUri = data.getData();
                if (imgUri != null) {
                    imgStrUri = imgUri.toString();
                    recipeImg.setImageURI(imgUri);
                    recipeImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imgBtn.setText(getString(R.string.remove_image));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The Uri of the image is then stored in a custom datastructure as a String (in the form of `imgStrUri`) and saved to sharedprefs using gson.

Later when I load the data from sharedpref to set the image in another activity the stored Uri no longer works and no image is put into my imageview.

```
String image = recipeCard.getRecipeImage();
        if (image != null) {
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_display)).setImageURI(Uri.parse(image));
        }
```

I did some debugging and found that although a Uri was saved to my datastructure (of which `recipeCard` is an instance) it no longer pointed to anything as nothing was loaded into my `ImageView`. So I went to run my `setImg` function again and chose the same picture only to find that the picture now had a slightly different Uri. So my question is, is this an emulator issue or have I done something wrong?

Here is an example of how the Uri changes:

content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F11/ORIGINAL/NONE/1007823737

content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F11/ORIGINAL/NONE/1302460634

As you can see the numbers after the last slash changes.

Haven't posted very many questions here so not very used to formulating my problem like this. As such I might very well have forgotten to provide some needed info or code snippets, if so please let me know and I'll get right on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have set up some code to pick an image from the gallery

`ACTION_PICK` does not take a MIME type.

> The Uri of the image is then stored in a custom datastructure as a String (in the form of imgStrUri) and saved to sharedprefs using gson.

That is not going to work well with `ACTION_PICK`. Your rights to access the content identified by the `Uri` [is going to be limited](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html). Quoting myself from that blog post:

> If you need durable access — such as being able to access the content
> tomorrow — you have two main options that I know of:

> 1. If you used `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, or similar
>    Storage Access Framework actions, you can try using `takePersistableUriPermissions()`
>    on `ContentResolver` to get long-term access to the content.

> 2. Otherwise, before your component is destroyed, make a local copy of
>    the content in your app's portion of internal storage (e.g., `getCacheDir()`).
>    This approach sucks,
>    as it duplicates the content, and changes to the original edition of the
>    content will not be reflected in the copy. Use appropriate UI terms
>    (e.g., "import") to help the user understand that this is what is going
>    on.

Do not assume that your `ACTION_PICK` `Uri` is going to be able to be used later, read back in from your JSON.

> So I went to run my setImg function again and chose the same picture only to find that the picture now had a slightly different Uri.

FWIW, there is no requirement for any `ACTION_PICK` implementation to return consistent `Uri` values. You see this sort of behavior elsewhere, such as there being multiple URLs under which you can get to this Web page.

Comment: So is there any way to consistently store a local image path so that my app can keep track of the image and use it where I want to?

Comment: @CalleAhlgren: Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` instead of `ACTION_PICK`. And, when you get the `Uri` in `onActivityResult()`, call `takePersistableUriPermissions()` on a `ContentResolver` to get long-term access to the content.

Comment: I'll be honest I have no idea whats actually happening but I put this line `getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(imgUri,
                        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);` in after `Uri imgUri = data.getData();` in `onActivityResult()` and it seems to work fine now, so thanks!

Comment: This seems such a strange way of doing things tho? Is the common practice to simply store the actual image in the app (using a SQLite or something along those lines) so as to not keep track of the image locally?

Comment: @CalleAhlgren: "This seems such a strange way of doing things tho?" -- think of a `Uri` as akin to a URL to some authenticated Web site. The URL might be good for a little while, but eventually, the authentication times out and the user has to log back in. Storing such a URL, assuming that you will always be able to access the content that it points to, is not going to work well. "Is the common practice to simply store the actual image in the app (using a SQLite or something along those lines) so as to not keep track of the image locally?" -- that is option 2 from my answer.

Comment: Not sure I understand, are you saying that in time even this new implementation will fail and I will have to choose the image again to refresh the Uri? If so then I am back to asking how can I make it permanent? Like how are for example profile pictures which have been chosen from the gallery stored in apps?

Comment: @CalleAhlgren: "are you saying that in time even this new implementation will fail and I will have to choose the image again to refresh the Uri?" -- no. `takePersistableUriPermission()` gives you long-term access to the content, as if you could ask the Web site for a "permalink" to replace your initial URL (in my previous analogy). The user could still do something that causes your `Uri` to break, such as delete the image, so there is no guarantee that the `Uri` will work forever.

Comment: @CalleAhlgren: "Like how are for example profile pictures which have been chosen from the gallery stored in apps? " -- in many cases, they do one of the two things that I list in my answer. Either they use `takePersistableUriPermission()` and save the `Uri`, or they copy the image into their app into a file that the app controls. In some cases, they might upload the profile image to their own server and have that as the "system of record", perhaps with a local cache of that image.

Comment: Thank you, you have been very helpful and patient!